# My code when run prints the output before it. I want it to print only what is required of that specific count number

Tags: python, for-loop, encryption, while-loop, count

Why does my code print the output before in the while loop.  I want to print only the count # and the encrypted text for that count #.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Also, what makes you think that the code prints something before it enters the `while` loop? It's really not clear what you expected to happen, and how reality is different from your expectations.

Comment: Please provide example input and output. Then explain what you want to be different in the output.

Comment: Your loop keeps adding elements to `list_text2`, so of course the output keeps growing longer. If that's not what you want, why are you doing it?

Answer (score 0):

put list_text2 inside your loop.

```
while count < 26:
    list_text2 = []
    for letter in list_text1:
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're appending to `list_test2` each time for a reason, so rather than sticking it outside of the loop, the following code should just slice the latest update off of the tail end of it, and print just that part only:

```
import string

text_to_encrypt = ('Please enter some text to encrypt: ')

offset = list(range(1,27))

alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
list_text2 = []
encrypted_text = ''
list_text1 = list(text_to_encrypt.lower())
adjusted_list = 2*alphabet

count = 1

while count < 26:
    for letter in list_text1:
        if letter not in alphabet:
            list_text2 += letter

        else:
            index = adjusted_list.index(letter)
            list_text2 += adjusted_list[index + offset[count]]

    list_text2_len = len(list_text2)
    slice_start_index = list_text2_len - len(text_to_encrypt)
    print(''.join(list_text2[slice_start_index:list_text2_len]))
    encrypted_text = ''.join(list_text2)
    count += 1
```